# json.stringfy alters the date

Tags: javascript, json, date

I am using JSON.Stringfy() to convert my date to String format. but the date so returns is the UTC time for my system.
here is the code.

```
var dateFrom;

dateFrom=new Date(); // outputs--> Wed Sep 24 2014 16:03:22 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) 

dateFrom=JSON.stringify(x); //outputs--> "2014-09-24T10:33:22.135Z" 

//Expected result--> "2014-09-24T16:03:22.135Z"
```

I think there is something which convert my current date to UTC date. is there any way to get the expected result..any comments would be valuable..
thanks in advance

Comment: It just called `Date.prototype.toISOString()` on your date object while stringifying. It dint change its value. You can still get the IST from the resultant string.

Comment: Why would you expect JSON.stringify to change your date from 4:03 in India to 4:03 in London?

Answer (score 0):

JSON follows a common format while it converts date objects into strings. Dates are encoded as ISO 8601 strings and then treated as strings while they get serialized.

But it doesnt mean that your date object got modified. It just got represented in a different format which enforced by JSON. So the date still points to the same timestamp which you refer via IST.

So your statement that it alters the date is wrong, it just alters the representation format.

```js
var d = new Date(); 
//shows local format
alert(d);

djson=JSON.stringify({"date":d}); 
//shows UTC format
alert(djson);

dobj=JSON.parse(djson);
//again UTC format 
alert(dobj.date);

d = new Date(dobj.date);
//again local format 
alert(d);
```

Comment: Ok I got it.but the thing is I want "2014-09-24T16:03:22.135" instead of "2014-09-24T10:33:22.135Z" which the json.stringfy returns..I dont want to get it in UTC format..I want my local time

Comment: run that snippet above. if you make a new date object with that UTC string, you can represent the date object in any timezone.

Comment: @mmithunsatheesh thanks for reply..sorry to mention again  I want something like 2014-09-24T16:03:22.135+05:30   but not in this in  UTC format.. your last alert gives me something like Wed Sep 24 2014 16:03:22 GMT+0530.. I want it in above format..Is there any way?